# What is the best approach to write Java code to simulate discrete time and tasks being done?

Tags: java, time, simulation

Assume I need to write a simulator with discrete time from [0, 1, 2, 3..., n].
I am a given a list of workers that will start a task at a certain time and take a specified amount of time to do so.
After a task is done, it is put on a queue that other workers will pick up and do (and then also put on the queue). A workers needs to do at least two other tasks submitted by a worker.
Once a task has been done by three workers, it's considered done and no longer needs to be put to the queue.

The only thing I'm not sure about is how to simulate time passing and workers doing things at a certain time.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) sorted by the simulation time to execute next. This way you efficient find the next task each time. Your task object might include a counter of how many times it has been started.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Actual time i.e. `java.util.Date` for the elapse time.
And for the work, an integer can be represented. As the worker works the integer will reduce and when it reaches to 0, the work is finished then you can calculate time required and works done by each worker.

Similar example:https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/java-multithreading/